# Чередование сообщений авторов как в диалоге

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Не могу никак сообразить , как сделать чередование сообщений 2х людей : слева и справа ?

В обычной  пользовательской части проблему просто решил проверкой своего имени и автора сообщения , т.к  это мои диалоги, а вот как разделить их теперь в админке , т.к диалоги тут от разных людей , в которых я не участвую .

Интересуют просто мысли , как можно реализовать, без кода . Спасибо [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: получить подзапросом прямо в списке выборки минимальный id участника для данного диалога. его налево, Не его - направо. Если подзапрос сильно грузит БД, то на переменных сделать, сортируем по диалогу, когда диалог сменился запоминаем в переменной первый встреченный id пользователя, и опять же на равно/не равно делим

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В обычной пользовательской части проблему просто решил проверкой
>   своего имени и автора сообщения...

Логически рассуждая, для других диалогов нам нужно взять имя одного автора и имя второго автора. Как их определить (как определить начало диалога) - другой вопрос. Например (такое решение используется также и тогда, когда в чате более 2 пользователей) создавать отдельную таблицу room для каждого случая переписки и добавлять туда пользователей.

Для 2 участников в вашем примере достаточно добавить колонку, например, room_id. И тогда каждое сообщение определенного диалога будет иметь определенный идентификатор, ну а дальше уже просто.